# Tensorflow math operation reduce_sum

Tags: tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.constant([[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]])
b = tf.constant([[5,4,3,2,1],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]])

product =tf.mul(a,b)
product_sum =tf.reduce_sum(tf.mul(a,b))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print product.eval()
    print product_sum.eval()
```

The result is :

```
[[ 5  8  9  8  5]

[ 1  4  9 16 25]

[ 1  4  9 16 25]]

145
```

But it is not the answer what i want.

I want to get the answer

[5+8+9+8+5,1+4+9+16+25,1+4+9+16+25]
                        =[35,55,55]

Comment: `product_sum = tf.reduce_sum(product, axis=1)`

Comment: Yes, you are right, That's awesome!! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As xxi mentioned in [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42303336/tensorflow-math-operation-reduce-sum#comment71762288_42303336), the correct solution here is to use the optional `axis` argument when calling [`tf.reduce_sum()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reduce_sum). In your case, you want to reduce along the column axis, so the following code will work:

```
product = tf.multiply(a, b)
product_sum = tf.reduce_sum(product, axis=1)
```

(Note also that in TensorFlow 1.0, `tf.mul()` is now [`tf.multiply()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/multiply).)